# Odd behavior of ListDensityPlot

Tags: plotting

I ran into some odd behavior with ListDensityPlot. I simplified the data as much as I could. If I simplify it further, the odd behavior goes away. What might be going on here?

```
$Version

10.4.1 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (April 11, 2016)

data =
 {{1, -0.04, 0}, {1, -0.01, 1}, {101, -0.04, 0}, {101, -0.01, 1},
  {201, -0.04, 0}, {201, -0.01, 1}, {301, -0.04, 0}, {301, -0.01, 1},
  {401, -0.04, 0}, {401, -0.01, 1}, {501, -0.04, 0}, {501, -0.01, 1},
  {601, -0.04, 0}, {601, -0.01, 1}}
```

Edit: So here the x-coordinate takes values 1,101,201,301,401,601 and y-coordinate -0.04,-0.01. The data values are just 0 and 1.

```
ListDensityPlot[data]
```

[image: ListDensityPlot image]

If I leave out just the 2 last data points, then everything works ok:

```
ListDensityPlot[data[[1 ;; 12]]]
```

[image]

Comment: The triangulation algorithm used to create the plot's mesh does not work properly if the data has a very large or very small aspect ratio.

Answer (score -1):

Your problem that the data is not in the form `{x, y, f[x,y]}`

Fix that this way:

```
ListDensityPlot[RotateRight /@ data]
```